# Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '??' has type 'String' which excludes null

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below 2 line code . I do say the controllers can be null in initialisation.
And if it is null, take empty string.
So why would it throw this error ?

```
final List<String>? controllers;
_nameController.text = widget.controllers[widget.index] ?? '';
```

Answer (score 5):

Try declaring like this:

```
final List<String?> controllers;
```